# Syntax error in pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
package wsplb1;

/**
 *
 * @author u108-11
 */
public class Wsp_1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Klasa1 k1 = new Klasa1();
        Klasa2 k2 = new Klasa2();

        try{
           Thread thread1 = new Thread(k1);
           Thread thread2 = new Thread(k2);

           thread1.setPriority(10);
           thread2.setPriority(1);

           thread1.start();
           thread2.start();

           Thread.sleep(5000); //zakończy się po 5 sec

           thread1.interrupt(); //oznaczon do przerwania, ale nie zabity
           thread2.interrupt();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println("Koniec wątku main");
    }
}
```

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

Comment: What you mean by that?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to downvote this question. After you edited it, you show no PDO code and no syntax error. This makes the question useless for anyone else reading it. The purpose of Stack Overflow is not to help *you*, it's to help the community.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to specify table or field names using placeholders. In other words you must change the `:name` in

```
 UPDATE tbl_ticket SET :name = :value WHERE id = :id
```

to a valid field name

```
 UPDATE tbl_ticket SET <field_name> = :value WHERE id = :id
```

or you could use a variable

```
 UPDATE tbl_ticket SET $your_field = :value WHERE id = :id
```

[PDO Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304)
[PDO::Prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#111977)

Comment: <field_name> is a variable? how to assign a value in here i need get in here the $name variable

Comment: Its working as : UPDATE tbl_ticket SET ".$name." = :fvalue WHERE id = :id" but might be not secure

Comment: Ok :) Get me upvote and I accept answer:3 cause I solved it myself.